# How to view div and model list in a selected tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to make a list of `offers`. Each list item will have the username, price, etc. The user will select the list item and click submit.  the select tags populate but the other info like username etc doesn't show up within the select tag.  I added a `select_tag` with `do` and put the username and other divs within but no use.

partial html:

```html
<div>
 <h>Choose an offer below </h>
</div>

<div>

 <%= form_tag select_offers_path do %>
 <% agreement.offers.each do |offer| %>
 <%= select_tag :offer_id, offer.id, class: "select-offer" do %>
 <div class="row" style="margin:0 auto;">


  <div>
            <%= 'hello' %>
   <%= offer.user.username %>
   $<%= offer.offered_price %>
  </div>

 </div>
 <% end %>

 <% end %>
 <%= submit_tag "Accept Offer" %>
 <% end %>

</div>
```

[image: selected tag]

Comment: instead of `form_tag` try using `form_for`. Depending on your model structures between `agreements` and `offers` you might need nested forms. Take a look at this link if that's the case http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: I tried using the form for but the same issue!. When I take out the selected tag  or f.select the list will show just not the selected type of course since it would be removed. I beleive its the way Im implementing the select_tag.. perhaps I dont use that specific tag and use a different type of select_tag.  are there other types of select_tags??